# My Prolog family tree program outputs/returns duplicated names

Tags: prolog

I am working on a family tree(Royal) implementation in prolog, and I am fairly new to prolog. So whenever I run:

```
| ?- brother_in_law(Who, diana).

Who = andrew ? ;

Who = andrew ? ;

Who = edward ? ;

Who = edward ? ;

no
```

As you can see, I'm getting these duplicates answers, and I was wondering if this is normal in prolog, or am I doing something wrong? How do I fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

This is my predicate for brother_in_law:

```
brother_in_law(B, X) :- male(B), brother(B, M), spouse(X, M).
```

Predicate for brother:

```
brother(X, Y) :- male(X), sibling(X, Y).
```

And final predicate siblings:

```
sibling(X, Y) :- child(X, P), child(Y, P), X \= Y.
```

Then I also have other facts such as male(edward), female(diana), and spouse(diana, charles), etc.

Comment: Without your code, there's no way to know if it's correct behavior or undesired. In practice, it certainly can happen; you can use `setof/3` to get _unique_ answers if that's all that matters. It's fairly common in beginner code to accidentally provide duplicate solutions by saying the same thing two different ways, overlapping base-cases, etc.

Comment: If you see your brother predicate where you pass `B` and for B you have already controlled that's it's male in brother_in_law predicate so you don't need to control it , instead do it for  `Y`

Comment: @DanielLyons It might be the case that I might have same things, since my trace went on forever checking both harry, and williams.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim It won't work that way, since it return a female for brother in law case.

Comment: @KonoDDa the best way is using graphical tracer . it's easy and you can also see the value on stack. It helped me a lot . So try that and see where you want your predicate call to go and where it goes. Simply type in `guitracer.` and then `trace.`

Comment: @LuaiGhunim it's giving me an error, when I type guitracer.

Comment: @KonoDDa it will not work in windows cmd i guess ,Open directly prolog and then type it there . In windows cmd you will get error